# Can style be applied only if the lower span class exists? Only CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello I have this html structure

```html
<span class="item-price">
  <del>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.</span>144 
    </span>
  </del>
  <ins>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.</span>139 
    </span>
  </ins>
  <span class="cityeduclass">➤ Incluye el envío a Lima</span>
  <span class="product-stock in-stock" tooltip="En Stock"></span>
</span>
```

I need to apply to but only if `.cityeduclass` exists | Only CSS

```css
span.item-price {
     background-color: red;
}
```

Any ideas Thanks?

Edit:
I need something like this
`span.item-price:has(span.cityeduclass)`

Comment: Short answer is no you cant just do that in CSS. with JavaScript No problem you can add and edit styles as much as you want ...

Comment: In the general case the answer is 'no'. However, in this very specific case, where you just want to give a background, there is a workaround using a pseudo element under specific conditions. Would that be of interest?

Comment: The background was an example css.
Actually the css is another. Thank you as well.